# Datos repetidos en un DropDownList MVC C#

Tags: html, c#, mvc

Desde la base de datos me traigo un campo que se repite varias veces en su tabla. Y el `DropDownList` se llena con ese campo. Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe algún método o alguna forma de que solo se muestre una vez?

Comment: Con que consulta traes esos datos al DropDownList

Comment: @Japv con una entidad que se le asigna a la base de datos, después con ese objeto llamo a la tabla y me traigo una lista de ese campo. no es un error de data, en la base de datos igual se repite varias veces, lo que quiero es solo mostrarlo una vez(solo para aclarar). para que se entienda mejor.
Entidad de la base de datos:
`private dbgycEntities3 db = new dbgycEntities3();` 

Lista que me traigo
`var nombreTablas = db.remepage.Select(x => x.nom_tabla ).ToList();
            var nombreTablasSL = new SelectList(nombreTablas); ViewBag.NombreTablas = nombreTablasSL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lista = db.remepage.Select(x => x.NombrePropiedad).Distinct().ToList();
```

Debes usar el **operador Distinct** de **Linq** el cual elimina los duplicados del campo que seleccionas.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! era lo que estaba buscando